# Permanent background service in AOSP Android?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm developing an Android app that is going to be embedded on a non-mobile device owned by our client, and used by our client's customers. My boss is envisioning a second app for the machine that runs in the background and sends data about the device to the backend periodically via a `Service`. I've employed [this method](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android), though I'm aware that it is imperfect because Android is prone to killing background services at will and at unspecified times, namely when it decides the service is obsolete or the system needs more memory.

That said, we are running the open-source version of Android (v5.1.1). I'm wondering if there are any options available to my OS team that aren't available for those building apps for the Google Android flavors, some way to remove those typical house-keeping mechanisms or auto-restart apps that have been closed?

Comment: Create a standard Linux daemon and start it as part of the boot process. Android's out-of-memory-killer only terminates the processes of standard Android SDK apps.

Answer (score 8):

Set [`android:persistent="true"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#persistent) on your `<application>` tag in the manifest.

The docs say:

> Whether or not the application should remain running at all times — "true" if it should, and "false" if not. The default value is "false". Applications should not normally set this flag; persistence mode is intended only for certain system applications.

For this to work, your APK will need to be installed on the system partition. It may also need to be in the `priv-app` dir or be signed with the same key as the system (some of these things do; I don't remember for this specific case).

Note that your `Application.onCreate()` will be started automatically; your `Service` will not be started automatically. Not that you need it; when you're `persistent`, the Android system won't (normally) kill your process, so you can just run normal threads doing what you need to.

Finally, make very sure that you're not leaking memory. Persistent apps are killed very late (if at all..?) by the LMK, so it could have adverse effects on the performance or stability of your device.

Comment: Will setting `android:persistent="true"` cause the service to restart even if the service itself calls `stopSelf()`?

Comment: No, `persistent` applies only to your *process*. Your `Application.onCreate()` will be called, but services that called `stopSelf()` are not automatically restarted.

Answer (score 4):

You have 3 options here in my opinion:

1. Modify Android OOMKiller to exclude your app. Wouldn't recommend this.
2. Create a Java system service, that is started by [SystemServer](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java)
3. Create a native C "app" (binary), that is started in one of the [init.rc scripts.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/rootdir/init.rc#823) ( The daemon suggested by CommonsWare comment ). This can have the benefit of being able to be run as root if you *need* it.

Comment: Sanchex, How we can access websocket and http apis in system services. Here i have posted my question if you would like to answer. Thanks.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72515189/aosp-how-we-can-access-websocket-and-http-apis-in-android-system-services-andr